# Http C++ client cannot connect to C++ server through internet

Tags: c++, http

I am trying to create a connection between my local application and my remote application. I used HTTP protocol, when testing in local network, my client-server code had successfully sent file to each other; however, the client couldn't connect to server when i pushed my server code to running on Cloud.

Below is my client-server code in C++. In the code, i tried to send an image from client to server.
**client.c**

```
#define EXAMPLE_RX_BUFFER_BYTES (921600)
#define IMAGE_SIZE 921600 

static int callback_example( struct lws *wsi, enum lws_callback_reasons reason, void *user, void *in, size_t len )
{
    switch( reason )
    {
        case LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_ESTABLISHED:
            lws_callback_on_writable( wsi );
            break;

        case LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_RECEIVE:
            break;

        case LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_WRITEABLE:
        {
            FILE * check_file;
            check_file = fopen("test_buff.jpg", "r");

            unsigned char buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + EXAMPLE_RX_BUFFER_BYTES + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING];
            fread(&buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], 1, IMAGE_SIZE, check_file);    
            printf("%ld\n", sizeof(buf));
            printf("hello\n");
            printf("%d\n", LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING);
            unsigned char *p = &buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING]; 
            size_t n = IMAGE_SIZE;
            lws_write( wsi, p, n, LWS_WRITE_TEXT );  //send 
            break;
        }

        case LWS_CALLBACK_CLOSED:   
        case LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR:
            web_socket = NULL;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

enum protocols
{
    PROTOCOL_EXAMPLE = 0,
    PROTOCOL_COUNT
};

static struct lws_protocols protocols[] =
{
    {
        "example-protocol",
        callback_example,
        0,
        EXAMPLE_RX_BUFFER_BYTES,
    },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 } /* terminator */
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    struct lws_context_creation_info info;
    memset( &info, 0, sizeof(info) );

    info.port = CONTEXT_PORT_NO_LISTEN;
    info.protocols = protocols;
    info.gid = -1;
    info.uid = -1;

    struct lws_context *context = lws_create_context( &info );

    time_t old = 0;
    while( 1 )
    {
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
        if( !web_socket && tv.tv_sec != old )
        {
            struct lws_client_connect_info ccinfo = {0};
            ccinfo.context = context;
            ccinfo.address = "https://http-server.wise-paas.io";
            ccinfo.port = 8080;
            ccinfo.path = "/";
            ccinfo.host = lws_canonical_hostname( context );
            ccinfo.origin = "origin";
            ccinfo.protocol = protocols[PROTOCOL_EXAMPLE].name;
            web_socket = lws_client_connect_via_info(&ccinfo);
        }

        if( tv.tv_sec != old )
        {
            lws_callback_on_writable( web_socket );
            old = tv.tv_sec;
        }

        lws_service( context, 250 );
        sleep(1);
    }

    lws_context_destroy( context );
    return 0;
}
```

**server.c**

```
static int callback_http( struct lws *wsi, enum lws_callback_reasons reason, void *user, void *in, size_t len )
{
    switch( reason )
    {
        case LWS_CALLBACK_HTTP:
            lws_serve_http_file( wsi, "example.html", "text/html", NULL, 0 );
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
int count = 0;
int length = 0;
struct payload
{
    unsigned char data[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + IMAGE_SIZE + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING];
    size_t len;
} received_payload;

static int callback_example( struct lws *wsi, enum lws_callback_reasons reason, void *user, void *in, size_t len )
{
    switch( reason )
    {
        case LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE:

            //while(length < IMAGE_SIZE){

            memcpy( &received_payload.data[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + length], in, len );

            // for(int i =16; i < (LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len); i++){
            //  printf("%c\t", received_payload.data[i]);
            // }
            length+=len;
            received_payload.len = length;
            // printf("\n\nlength: %d \n", length);
            //}
            lws_callback_on_writable_all_protocol( lws_get_context( wsi ), lws_get_protocol( wsi ) );
            //unsigned char *p = &received_payload.data[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING];
            // count++;
            if(length >= 921600){
                length = 0;
                }

            printf("hello for saving\n");
            printf("%d\n%d\n", len, sizeof(received_payload.data));

            FILE *receive_test;

            receive_test = fopen("write", "w");
            fwrite(&received_payload.data[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], 1, IMAGE_SIZE, receive_test);

            fclose(receive_test);

            break;

        case LWS_CALLBACK_SERVER_WRITEABLE:
            lws_write( wsi, &received_payload.data[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], received_payload.len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT );
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

enum protocols
{
    PROTOCOL_HTTP = 0,
    PROTOCOL_EXAMPLE,
    PROTOCOL_COUNT
};

static struct lws_protocols protocols[] =
{
    /* The first protocol must always be the HTTP handler */
    {
        "http-only",   /* name */
        callback_http, /* callback */
        0,             /* No per session data. */
        0,             /* max frame size / rx buffer */
    },
    {
        "example-protocol",
        callback_example,
        0,
        EXAMPLE_RX_BUFFER_BYTES,
    },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 } /* terminator */
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    struct lws_context_creation_info info;
    memset( &info, 0, sizeof(info) );

    info.port = 8080;
    info.protocols = protocols;
    info.gid = -1;
    info.uid = -1;

    struct lws_context *context = lws_create_context( &info );

    while( 1 )
    {
        lws_service( context, /* timeout_ms = */ 1000000 );
    }

    lws_context_destroy( context );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without looking at the code, this sounds more like a firewall problem then a programming problem. Have you checked that your port 8080 is actually reachable on the server side?

Comment: This LWS framework seems to support error callbacks. Have you tried adding log statements to these callbacks? Alternatively, have you tried tracing the system calls client and server make? (strace or procmon)

Comment: Also, you specify a https:// url but your server contains no trace of a TLS implementation. Are you _sure_ this worked locally?

Comment: Why not use a platform independent implementation like [httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/)? HTTP(S) Server would be set up in 5 or so statements; client in 3. Don't use the Windows API, when you don't have to, it's ugly.